# How to restore a .backup file from a single table on postgres?

Tags: postgresql, backup, dump

I have a .backup dump from a single table, but it didn't work restore like a normal backup from an entire db. I'm creating this backup file with the following batch script `bin\pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -v -f %BACKUP_FILE% --table <schema.table-name> <db-name>` And i'm restoring it with the pgadmin restore option, i didn't get any error message, the restore run normally, but the table don't show on my db/schema.

Comment: That you chose to name the file with a ".backup" extension doesn't tell us anything.  How did you create it?  What command did you use to restore it?  What error did you get?

Comment: I edited the question putting the information that was missing on it.

Comment: I din't named the bakcup file ".backup", it was the extension that file was saved.

Comment: pgadmin3 or pgadmin4?

Comment: "pg_dump" follows the Linux philosophy, not Windows.  It doesn't add suffixes, so .backup must have already been included in '%BACKUP_FILE%', however it got there.

Comment: I'm using pgadmin4.

Comment: If I take a single table backup like you describe and restore with pgAdmin4, it either works, or I get an error message.  Perhaps it is successfully restoring, but into a different database than you were expecting?  Can you check the PostgreSQL server logs, to see of there is an error message there which is just not getting displayed on pgAdmin4?

Comment: Checking the log errors i get this: 
pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
pg_restore: creating TABLE "rep.soadotadas"
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 727; 1259 430835 TABLE soadotadas postgres
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  type "public.geometry" does not exist
LINE 7:     geom public.geometry(Point,31982)

Apparently it is a problem with postgis.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you tried so far, please post error message for better understanding,

Try below and post a comment if this works for you or not.

you can use [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) to restore a single table :

`pg_restore -t my_table -d database_name database.dump`

If the dump is not too big, the easiest thing to do is restore the full backup to a temporary database `(gzcat backup_file.gz | psql -h host -U user database_name)` dump the one table `(pg_dump -t my_table)`, then restore it.

Comment: I did run the first script, but it ask for a password when the db where i was tryingto restore the table dons't has a password.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i was trying to restore a postgis table on a db which did not have the postgis extension. Was just a matter of running the command `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` on the query tool.